# JAXB: generate javadoc from binding file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a maven project with my `src/main/java` folder and my `src/main/resources` folder. Under resources, I placed my xsd file and the following jxb file. The plan is to create javadoc comments based on the binding file when I run maven generate-sources together with the xjc goal to generate the classes themselves. The classes are generated successfully, but are documented with the contents of the documentation tags inside the xsd file (which I don't want, I want the javadoc comments from the jxb file).

This is the jxb file:

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="https://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ?>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="mySchema.xsd" node="//xsd:schema">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='MyType']">
            <jxb:class name="MyType">
                <jxb:javadoc>MY DOCS</jxb:javadoc>
            </jxb:class>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

There is no error whatsoever, but the classes are generated as if the binding file wasn't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. Apart from a small error in the file itself (I had to use http instead of http**s** for the namespaces) the real issue was the file extension. The jaxb maven plugin searches for `xjb` files, mine had the extension `jxb`.

Answer (score 1):

See [Customizing JAXB Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html).

The `<javadoc>` tag must be inside a `<package>`, `<class>`, `<property>`, `<typesafeEnumClass>`, or `<typesafeEnumMember>` tag.

Example from the linked document (inline binding declaration):

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
   <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:appinfo>
         <jxb:class name="POType">
            <jxb:javadoc>
            A &lt;b>Purchase Order&lt;/b> consists of 
addresses and items.
            </jxb:javadoc>
         </jxb:class>
      </xsd:appinfo>
   </xsd:annotation>
   .
   .
   .
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution with external binding. However, I'll try to wrap it in a `class` tag.

Comment: I edited my question to update the jxb file, surrounding the `javadoc` tag with a `class` tag. This doesn't help the missing doc generation unfortunateley.